# calculate combination in C# without recursive function

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations

i would like to calculate all the combination possible, but i don't want to use recursive function just some simple code in C# ?

Here is example :

```
                     col1     col2   col3
       valueinf=      5        6      7
       valuesup=     10       20     30
```

i want this for result:

```
        res1 = 5+6+7
        res2 = 5+6+30
        res3 = 5+20+7
        res4 = 5+20+30
        res5 = 10+6+7
        res6 = 10+6+30
        res7 = 10+20+7
        res8 = 10+20+30
```

the number of colonne is variable but i wil allways have 2 lines one inferior and one superior.
I don't know how to begin the algorithm. Some help will be gratefull just to begin

Comment: how much col in this case ? is it always three ?

Comment: Please share the code you are using. For example - how are the values stored? is it a csv file? 2 lists? we will be able to help only if more data is shared

Comment: in this case i have 3 col.

Comment: i have a list of int like you see in my exmple

Answer (score 0):

Well, will-nilly you have to loop:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<int> Sums(IEnumerable<int[]> columns) {
  if (columns is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(columns));

  int[][] data = columns.ToArray();
  int[] pos = new int[data.Length];

  do {
    yield return Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Sum(i => data[i][pos[i]]);

    for (int i = pos.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (pos[i] == data[i].Length - 1)
        pos[i] = 0;
      else {
        pos[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
  }
  while (!pos.All(p => p == 0));
}
```

The very same idea if you want to print formulae:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Formulae(IEnumerable<int[]> columns) {
  if (columns is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(columns));

  int[][] data = columns.ToArray();
  int[] pos = new int[data.Length];

  do {
    yield return string.Join("+", Enumerable
      .Range(0, data.Length).Select(i => data[i][pos[i]]));

    for (int i = pos.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (pos[i] == data[i].Length - 1)
        pos[i] = 0;
      else {
        pos[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
  }
  while (!pos.All(p => p == 0));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
List<int[]> columns = new List<int[]>() {
  new int[] {5, 10},
  new int[] {6, 20},
  new int[] {7, 30}, 
};

var sums = Sums(columns);
var formulae = Formulae(columns);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sums
  .Select((v, i) => $"res{i+1} = {v}")));

Console.WriteLine();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, formulae
  .Select((v, i) => $"res{i+1} = {v}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
res1 = 18
res2 = 41
res3 = 32
res4 = 55
res5 = 23
res6 = 46
res7 = 37
res8 = 60

res1 = 5+6+7
res2 = 5+6+30
res3 = 5+20+7
res4 = 5+20+30
res5 = 10+6+7
res6 = 10+6+30
res7 = 10+20+7
res8 = 10+20+30
```

**Edit:** To find the best fit you can exploit the very same principle:

```
private static (int[] pos, int diff, string formula) BestFit(int target, IEnumerable<int[]> columns) {
  if (columns is null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(columns));

  int[][] data = columns.ToArray();
  int[] pos = new int[data.Length];

  int bestDiff = -1;
  int[] bestPos = null;

  do {
    int diff = Math.Abs(target - Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Sum(i => data[i][pos[i]]));

    if (diff < bestDiff || bestPos == null) {
      bestPos = pos.ToArray();
      bestDiff = diff;
    }

    for (int i = pos.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (pos[i] == data[i].Length - 1)
        pos[i] = 0;
      else {
        pos[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
  }
  while (!pos.All(p => p == 0));

  return (
    bestPos,
    bestDiff,
    string.Join("+", Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Select(i => data[i][bestPos[i]]))
  );  
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  int[][] data = new int[][] {
    new int[] {5, 10},
    new int[] {6, 20},
    new int[] {7, 30},
  };

  var fit = BestFit(20, data);

  Console.Write($"delta = {fit.diff}; formula = {fit.formula}");
```

**Outcome:**

```
  delta = 2; formula = 5+6+7
```

Comment: ok so you use linq.now with all the combination i need to calculate the best combination near  a result that i want.

For Exemple : the resulat is 20 so the best combination is the first one because it's the nearest from 20 and keep this combination

Comment: @Newbie_thefirst: you can exploit the very same principle and similar code (see my edit)

Comment: i don't understand all the code but it works. is it possible to have the same algorithme without using ienumerable but List

Comment: @Newbie_thefirst: `IEnumerable<T>` is *more general* then collections like `List<T>`, `T[]`, `HashSet<T>` etc.: all these collections implement `IEnumerable<T>`. That's why you can safely pass array or list to the current implementation. However if you like, you can just replace `IEnumerable<T>` by `List<T>`

Comment: can you tell me how to get an element at a position in a list ?
i want to use the sum with the List<int[]>but i can t take the value at the pos

Comment: @Newbie_thefirst: Your question is unclear; to get `i`-th from `list`, put `list[i]`. If you ask about the solution, my `BestFit` method returns *tuple* with `pos` property (as well as `diff` and `formula`). `pos` is an array each item of which is the index you should take. For instance, if `pos == {1, 1, 0}` you should take `data[0][1] + data[1][1] + data[2][0]`.

Comment: i have this  List<int[]> lstdata = new List<int[]>();
 int[] pos = new int[lstdata.Count];

in your example you use 
 int resultat = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length).Sum(i => data[i][pos[i]]);

how to i use linq with list to make the sum

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, data.Count).Sum(i => data[i][pos[i]]);` if `data` is list